# Closing MeasureTool Window

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, tools, measurements

I'm activating the built in ArcGIS measure tool using the following code:

```
ControlsMapMeasureTool measureTool = new ControlsMapMeasureToolClass();
measureTool.OnCreate(_axMapControl.Object);

// set current tool to be measure tool
_axMapControl.CurrentTool = measureControl as ITool;

// deactivate measure tool
_axMapControl.CurrentTool = null;
```

Whenever I deactivate the tool the window opened by the tool is not closed.  How can I cause it to close?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there is no interface for the measure tool dialog and thus no way to close it using ArcObjects. I think you'll have to use the Windows API functions [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the child window handle corresponding to the measure tool dialog, and [`DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to close it and release its memory resources.

See pinvoke.net for C# function definitions for these:

- [FindWindowEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html)
- [DestroyWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.destroywindow)